# Where to find the topic scope of a Stack Exchange section/site?

Tags: support, scope

I think that each Stack Exchange site (e.g., "Robotics", "Stack Overflow", ...) has their own explanation of the topic scope - what is allowed and what not.

But where to find it? Sorry I can not see a link for that and often ask "wrong" questions at the "wrong" place.

Answer (score 7):

Two places to look at:

- The [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) (at `/tour`) on every site
- The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) (at `/help`) - again, for every site, there will be two articles on what is on-topic and what isn't

You can find them in the "help" menu in the top bar, and as links on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Those two articles can be found under `/help/on-topic` and `/help/dont-ask` (though the latter isn't site-specific).

Comment: How does one navigate to this via the UI? Any way to do it besides direct URL?

Comment: Found it through UI. Any SE site, click the `?` circle icon on the top right > Help Center > Under `Asking` > Click ` What topics can I ask about here?`

Answer (score 4):

Every site has a [What's on topic?](/help/on-topic) page. Just navigate to `https://something.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic` and you'll find it.